# Binding not working for array

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the data template as for TreeView Control as,

```
        DataTemplate cardLayout = new DataTemplate();
        cardLayout.DataType = typeof(NumberSystem);

        FrameworkElementFactory Stack = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        Stack.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);

        FrameworkElementFactory Data = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        MultiBinding b = new MultiBinding();
        for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            Binding nn = new Binding("bits["+(Count - 1 - i).ToString()+"]");
            b.Bindings.Add(nn);
        }
        b.Converter = new BitConverter();
        b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        b.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;
        Data.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, b);
        Stack.AppendChild(Data);

        cardLayout.VisualTree = Stack;

        Map.ItemTemplate = cardLayout;

        NumberSystem.Size=32;
        NumberSystem n=new NumberSystem("0AF45000");
```

Map is the name of the TreeView Control in the UI.The Data textblock has multiple binding to character array of Registers class**.But the problem is Only one time the binding is made during the initialization of elements.Other times when the char array is changed the changes are not reflected in the TextBlock in UI.**

```
      public class BitConverter : IMultiValueConverter
      {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType,
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
        string binary="";
        for (var i =0;i< Registers.RegisterSize;i++)
        { 
            binary+=values[i].ToString();
        }
        string hex = System.Convert.ToString(System.Convert.ToInt32(binary, 2), 16);
        hex = hex.PadLeft(8, '0');
        return "0x"+hex.ToUpper();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes,
           object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
         return new NotImplementedException();
        }
     }

public class NumberSystem
{
    public static int Size;
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public char[] bits { get; set; }

    public char this[int index]
    {
        get { return bits[index]; }
        set
        {
            bits[index] = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Binding.IndexerName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public NumberSystem(string Data)
    {
        int i = Convert.ToInt32(registerData, 16);
        string s = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(RegisterSize, '0');
        bits = new char[Size];
        for (var itr = 0; itr < Size; itr++)
        {
            bits[itr] = s.ElementAt(Size-1-itr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Delete all your code and start reading [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way).

Comment: BTW, I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but your approach seems extremely convoluted. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: The thing I am trying to achieve is data binding between the array property of an ordinary class to the TextBlock in a treeview of the  UI.But the binding is happening only when I initialize the class

Comment: Your multibinding approach is not optimal. In fact, your entire approach is far from optimal. It sounds like you're just creating a String to show in a TextBlock from a Char array? why not simply `var str = new string(bits)`?

Comment: Actually I have one text block that holds hexadecimal value and textboxes that holds the equivalent binary values for the hex values (each bit in a textbox).The source for the hexadecimal value is a property "Data" from the class NumberSystem. How am I supposed to implement this binding